# How to start external program from Python script in the foreground?

Tags: python

```
import os
os.system("notepad macros.txt")
```

or

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen(["notepad", "macros.txt"])
```

both start notepad in the background. How to start it in the foreground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the [start](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm) command, maybe the /MAX option will force notepad to be in foreground, otherwise if you can wait untill notepad shutdown, use the /WAIT option/

```
Popen(["start", "/MAX", "notepad", "macros.txt"], shell=True)
```

Comment: It seems this code does not work in Windows: "WindowsError: [Error 2]"

Comment: @DSblizzard : I add the `shell=True` parameter (otherwise you'll have to specify the complete pathes), on my WindowsXP it works even without the /MAX option.

Comment: is possible to populate a cmd? something like process = subprocess.Popen(["start", "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", "cd C:/folder;dir"], shell=True)   I want to be able to open 3 cmd windows and start certain programs from there.